# INITCAP function in Oracle SQL View

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have created a table view like this:

```
SELECT
   census_regions AS "Regions",
   all_markets AS "Markets",
   bc_department AS "Department",
   bc_super_category AS "Super Category",
   hw_organic AS "Organic"
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE all_markets != 'unknown'
```

I'd like to "wrap" it into INITCAP function, so every value in my table would be Proper Case. But the renaming causes problems and I really need the columns to be renamed. 
I tried brackets, but it gives me errors anyway.

Thank you very much.
Nikola

Comment: can you share orginal issue where you got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this one column at a time:

```
SELECT initcap(census_regions) AS Regions,
       initcap(all_markets) AS Markets,
       initcap(bc_department) AS Department,
       initcap(bc_super_category) AS "Super Category",
       initcap(hw_organic) AS Organic
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE all_markets <> 'unknown';
```

Do not use escape column names unless you have to.  I would recommend that you rename `Super Category` so there is no space in the name.